# Python canvas grid

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In `tkinter`, if I use `canvas.grid`, the `canvas.bind` cannot work, and shows `_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "button"` but if I use `canvas.pack`, it won't. Can anyone help me figure out?

Here is a part of the code

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("project")
window.geometry('760x560')
window.resizable(False, False)
```

```
def mouse_click_handler(event):
    # Get the coordinates of the mouse click
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
  
    screen_two.canvas.create_oval(event.x - 15, event.y - 15,
                            event.x + 15, event.y + 15,
                            fill = piece_color, tags = ("show_piece"))
```

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg = "green", width = 540, height = 540)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 6
for i in range(15): # draw line
        canvas.create_line(32, (35 * i + 38), 522, (35 * i + 38))
        canvas.create_line((35 * i + 32), 38, (35 * i + 32), 528)
    point_X = [3, 3, 11, 11, 7]
    point_Y = [3, 11, 3, 11, 7]
    for i in range(5): # draw dot
        canvas.create_oval(35 * point_X[i] + 28, 35 * point_Y[i] + 33,
                        35 * point_X[i] + 36, 35 * point_Y[i] + 41, fill = "black")
    count = 0
    for i in range(15):
        label1 = tk.Label(canvas, text = str(i+1), fg = "black", bg = "green")
        label2 = tk.Label(canvas, text = str(i+1), fg = "black", bg = "green")
        label1.place(x = 35 * count + 25, y = 2)
        label2.place(x = 2, y = 35 * count + 25)
        count += 1
    canvas.bind("<button-1>", mouse_click_handler)
```

Comment: Tk event types are case-sensitive - `<button-1>` is not a valid event.

Comment: oh I know what do you mean, thank you.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the question. Instead, post an answer (yes, you can [answer your own question](/help/self-answer)), then after 48 hours, you can click the checkmark to [accept it](/help/accepted-answer), which basically marks the issue as solved. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].